# Linux, поиск файла в директории

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется директория, в которой в процессе работы сторонней программы в какой-то момент должен появиться файл package.lock, играющий роль мьютекса, и сразу после этого папка package.

Пока имеется файл .lock, папку package нельзя использовать, там идет сохранение файлов.

Пишу скрипт на bash, который сначала определит факт наличия папки package, затем будет ждать удаления сторонней программой файла package.lock.

```
DIR=<my_dir>
LOCK=$DIR.lock

exists=False
locked=True

while [ "$exists" == 'False' ]
do
  files=($(ls . ))
  if [[ " ${files[*]} " =~ $DIR ]]; then
    echo appeared
    unset files
    break
  else
    echo still not exists
    unset files
    sleep 10
  fi
done



while [ "$locked" == 'True' ]
do
  files=($(ls . ))
  if [[ " ${files[*]} " =~ $LOCK ]]; then
    echo still locked
    unset files
    sleep 10
  else
    echo unlocked
    unset files
    break
  fi
done
```

На этапе тестирования делаю следующее: запускаю этот скрипт в пустой директории, он мне с периодичностью 10 сек пишет, что папки package нет, потом я создаю файл package.lock и скрипт мне выдает, что директория появилась, но еще не разблокирована (не разблокирована - значит, что файла package.lock все еще присутствует).

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так...

Comment: Во-первых, вы проверяете наличие строки `package` в выводе команды ls, и так как эта команда выводит `package.json`, то вполне очевидно, что строка `package` действительно находится внутри строки `package.json` и проверка успешно срабатывает. Во-вторых, а зачем вы вообще используете ls, чем не угодили стандартные шелловые проверки существования каталога или файла `[ -d "$DIR" ]` или `[ -f "$LOCK" ]` соответственно?

Comment: В-третьих, если я правильно понял суть скрипта (ждать, пока нет каталога или есть файл), то весь этот скрипт ужимается всего в одну строку `while [ ! -d "$DIR" -o -f "$LOCK" ]; do sleep 10; done`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое, я просто не продвинутый юзер, как Вы поняли, поэтому Ваши подсказки очень помогли, еще раз большое спасибо!